# I have two identical .htaccess. How do I create one in root folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess in root. Same one is in folder /enter

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?content=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&content=$2
```

How do I turn on the folder "enter" in the root .htaccess and remove duplicate htaccess ?

Comment: copy from /enter to root? not sure i get the question

Comment: Yes, I did that. But I want one htaccess, not two! Problem is args in subfolder fly in root. I dont want that.

Comment: once copied delete the other file.

Comment: .htaccess must be in root, not in subfolder. For now this is work for me, but i have two htaccess. Whether be one?

Comment: When I delete a .htaccess from subfolder then I get the error in accepting variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

## Enter
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/enter$ enter/index.php?lang=$1&content=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/enter/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ enter/index.php?lang=$1&content=$2 [L]

## Root
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?content=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&content=$2
```

By the way: The **[L]** means "last":
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: I understand your point. Although, for my needs, I will have little to change.
Thank you.